# Centering control vertically in relation to chunk of text in textbox

Tags: c#, position, controls, centering

I have a textbox with some html elements in it, each presented as a separate chunk of text. Now I want to add some pictureboxes, one for each element, centered vertically to the left of their corresponding elements (in case of nested elements, such as the p inside the div in the example, div should take precedence and p should be ignored).

The code I've come up with so far is obviously missing something, since the Y coordinates are not correct. See picture below where the two black blobs represent two pictureboxes:

[image]

And here's the code:

```
string str = textBox1.Text;
string pattern = "<(?<tag>div|p|h[1-6])>";
Regex r = new Regex(pattern);
Match m = r.Match(str);
int i = 1;
while (m.Success) {
    string new_s = str.Substring(m.Index + 3);
    string new_p = "</" + m.Groups["tag"].Value + ">";
    Match m_end = Regex.Match(new_s, new_p);
    if (m_end.Success) { // Corresponding end tag exists
        Point start_p = textBox1.GetPositionFromCharIndex(m.Index);
        Point end_p = textBox1.GetPositionFromCharIndex(m_end.Index);
        double top = start_p.Y;
        double bottom = end_p.Y;
        int midpoint = (int)(top + bottom) / 2;
        PictureBox pictureBox = new PictureBox();
        pictureBox.Name = "pictureBox" + i.ToString();
        pictureBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(15, midpoint + 7);
        pictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile("c:\\blob.png");
        pictureBox.Size = new Size(15, 15);
        pictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
        this.Controls.Add(pictureBox);
        m_end.Index.ToString());
    }
    i++;
    m = r.Match(str, m_end.Index);
}
```

I've also tried to add textBox1.Font.Size to the equation, but that didn't help. And line height is difficult since each chunk is technically one line. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Edit: Since Point is based on the top left corner, it seems reasonable that Font.Size should be used to find the bottom. And that seems to give the correct position for the first blob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution. Basically, since the input string is shortened every time a new tag is searched for, the end tag position gets wrong if I don't add the number of characters removed from the search string. Or in code, which hopefully is a bit clearer:

```
while (m.Success) {
    string new_s = str.Substring(m.Index);
    string new_p = "</" + m.Groups["tag"].Value + ">";
    Match m_end = Regex.Match(new_s, new_p);
    Point start_p = textBox1.GetPositionFromCharIndex(m.Index);
    Point end_p = textBox1.GetPositionFromCharIndex(m_end.Index + m.Index);
    int top = (int)start_p.Y;
    int bottom = (int)(end_p.Y + textBox1.Font.Size);
    if (m_end.Success) {
        int midpoint = (top + bottom) / 2;
        PictureBox pictureBox = new PictureBox();
        pictureBox.Name = "pictureBox" + i.ToString();
        pictureBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(15, midpoint + 7 + 2);
        pictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile("c:\\blob.png");
        pictureBox.Size = new Size(15, 15);
        pictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
        this.Controls.Add(pictureBox);
    }
    i++;
    m = r.Match(str, m_end.Index + m.Index);
}
```